# Parcel/Serialize ClassLoader

Tags: android, classloader, serializable, parcelable

I'm wondering if it's possible to parcel (or serialize) a `ClassLoader` to send it through a `Message` to another process in Android. [`ClassLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) doesn't implement `Parcelable`/`Serializable`.

Any hints on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, interesting question, I found a live example of Serializable ClassLoader [here](http://ejoe.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ejoe/EJOE/src/de/netseeker/ejoe/EJClassLoader.java?revision=1.28&view=markup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Class loader

A class loader is basically a hash table whose entries are keyed by class name and points to byte code loaded in the VM. Byte code loaded in the VM itself is of course off limits to Java processes, as Java does not allow you to manipulate code. Note that the bytecode has been compiled by the JIT VM into CPU-specific code and will contain memory locations and other low-level constructs.

It is possible to share class loaders (via serialization or otherwise) *within the same VM*, since the class loader will still be able to point to the *original* byte code. However, in order to serialize then deserialize into another VM, the class loader would have to serialize the byte code. And there is the problem.

### Serializing a class loader

As a thought experiment, how would we serialize the code so that the other process could deserialize it?

We would have to handle this as class-sized chunks so the serialized entity has the entire class interface. We would have to 'unresolve' pointers in the bytecode to symbols. We would also have to copy the entire string and symbol table for the class so introspection continues to work.

What we have just defined is the class file itself (a slight difference being the initialisation vs. serialisation of class members)

Let me repeat that: A **class file** *is* the serialized version of a class.

### The DEX conundrum

However, Android pre-compiles class files into the DEX. This is a single file which contains an optimized version of a JAR - classes are pre-linked with each other and all strings symbols sit in the same shared string/symbol pools. So, in Android, you the smallest sharable component is the DEX.

In many instances app or device makers create an ODEX file. This is a DEX file that has been compiled to a specific CPU and architecture (including big-endian or little-endian systems).

In Android you can think of the ODEX file as the serialized class loader.

### Remote class loading

The crux of the problem is how one process can load class files visible to the original process. [yorkw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873875/yorkw) suggested a [class loader](http://ejoe.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ejoe/EJOE/src/de/netseeker/ejoe/EJClassLoader.java?revision=1.28&view=markup) s/he found which does something like what I have suggested. The approach is that the first process implements a class-lookup service, returning the class bytecode. However this won't work on Android directly because of the DEX problem listed above.

### Solution?

Any solution that you implement is therefore going to be based on the (O)DEX. You basically need to have your client talk to your server and request a (O)DEX file, then load it as a single entity. Loading it will return your new class loader

Now, I have never done this, and it is entirely possible that Android allows just one DEX file to be loaded scuppering this approach. YMMV

I do hope this discussion helps...

---

**TL;DR** You can't serialize a class loader; however you *might* be able to persuade another process to load a (O)DEX file which would produce the same result.

Comment: Hi Andrew. What if I serialize the `getClass` instance of my object? `Class` is-a `Serializable` and also has a `getClassLoader` method.

Comment: @gthanop It depends what you want to do with the Serialized instance. The Serialized form does not include the bytecode not the ClassLoader, so deserialising it is going to be impossible unless you are in the same JVM as the original Class. Even then you will have weird behavior - you would have a second Class instance representing the same Class.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's unfortunately not possible. Some subset of ClassLoader might be possible to make parcelable, but I'd really advice against it.

If your problem is that you're trying to read a custom class from a `Parcel` in a different application, you should be able to read it by copying the class to the other application (making sure it's in the same package in both applications). All you have to do is to in the first application write it to a parcel like this:

```
parcel.writeParcelable(myCustomParcelable, 0);
```

And in the other end, where you receive the parcel, just read it like this:

```
MyCustomParcelable myCustomParcelable = (MyCustomParcelable)parcel.readParcelable(getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Copying the class is not a solution. This is a service. Applications connect to it and deliver information. I want the applications to be able to extend the API classes and successfully deliver them to the service.

Comment: If that is the case, you need to use a service binding. I'd suggest writing a wrapper class that initiates the service binding and wraps aidl calls to the service. Then you'd be able to make it possible to subclass your class and do calls to the service. You can read more about how to use aidl here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: I already looked at AIDL before opting for Messenger. Quoting the page: *"If you have a class that you would like to send from one process to another through an IPC interface, you can do that. However, you must ensure that **the code for your class is available to the other side of the IPC channel** and your class must support the Parcelable interface."* This has no use for me.

Comment: In that case I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. Copying the class is a way to make it available on the other side of the IPC channel. But even if you have that, making calls on that object would not in any way communicate with the service.

Comment: I want the *client* (application) to be able to extend the *server* (service) classes, and be able to send them to the server. I cannot have all classes that third-parties may create by extending. But I want to access the father's methods of this classes, not the child's (of course, since I don't even know what would they be).

Comment: This is very insecure: essentially you want people to send you code, and you will run it for them? Don't do this. Technically, you could send DEX blobs and load them, then use reflection to run whatever code is inside, but it is still not a good idea. May be you should rethink your design, or at least describe the bigger picture, so people can offer alternate solutions.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov Forgot to answer you sorry. Thanks for your insight, but it is not insecure as this is not meant for standard Android use (e.g. phones/tablets) but a propietary hardware and to allow third parties to develop. In any case I finally didn't serialize the ClassLoader, it just makes no sense (but it did for me at that time :))

Answer (score 1):

Given the strong native component of ClassLoader, along with What It Does, I cannot imagine that it is any way possible to share ClassLoaders with other processes, at least not in any way that would be meaningful.

Comment: With "other processes" in Android I meant Java processes of course. Please read my comment on Marcus' answer about "meaningful".